# JavaScript IE8: Add a function to a NodeList object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a reference to a NodeList, and I simply want to attach a function to the object for later invoking by another area of the script.

```
// Quick and dirty hack to obtain a NodeList from given element(s):
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    nodeList;
fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById("test").cloneNode(true));

nodeList = fragment.childNodes;
console.log(nodeList);

// How can a method be defined on the nodeList in IE8?
nodeList["someMethod"] = function() { alert("YOU WIN!"); };
nodeList.someMethod();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gCwAr/

The above code works in these browsers: IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera.

My question is **how to get the code working in IE8**, as the following error is thrown on the penultimate line:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 1):

Extending host objects such as DOM objects is [generally a bad idea](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). Just don't do it. Instead, wrap the NodeList in your own object which has your extra method.

Comment: The reason I'm using a NodeList rather than my own object, is because I want to use `.defineProperty()` on the object, and in IE8 (which, unfortunately, I have to support), it is only possible on DOM objects...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in IE8, by defining the property on the DOM class prototype first, eg.:

```
var nodeList = document.body.childNodes;
// Define a property with the same name on the prototype object first,
// to enable defining the property on the NodeList
NodeList.prototype.myMethod = undefined;
nodeList.myMethod = function () { alert("Method"); };
nodeList.myMethod();
```